# How to properly give values to java-beans using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

This is the jsp tag i'm using

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="request" class="business.Bean">
    <p>Name is <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="name"/></p><br>
    <p>Surname is <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="surname"/></p><br>
</jsp:useBean>
```

And this is how i setup the bean from the servlet `request.getSession().setAttribute("user", new Bean("MyName", "MySurname"));`
. This set up works when i'm using *el* but when i use it here i have a double output of "Empty", which is the default empty constructor of the bean, how am i supposed to make it work here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use the class  attribute you accualy create a new instance of that class and you put it the scope request that's why you your bean comes with two empty properties , but that is not what you want to do  , you want to retrieve the bean that you have set in the request scope using the `request.getSession().setAttribute("user", new Bean("MyName", "MySurname"));`

**so you should change the class attribute with type attribute**

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="session" type="business.Bean">
</jsp:useBean>
<p>Name is <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="name"/></p><br>
<p>Surname is <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="surname"/></p><br>
```

Comment: if i remove the class and replace it type in the tag "<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="request" type="business.Bean">" i have "HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index2.jsp at line 11" which is that line

Comment: my bad i have edited the answer the <jsp:getProperty/> should be outside <jsp:useBean></jsp:useBean>

Comment: oh i see the bean is in the scope of session not request so to retrieve it you should use session for scope attribute